# Swift Radio Buttons - CheckBoxes - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, checkbox

I work on Swift 3, and I'm trying to make checkboxes that behave like radio buttons. I explain myself : I have 8 buttons ; each has an "unchecked" image and a "checked" image. I want only 1 button to be selected (so, showing ITS "checked" image) at the time. The principle of radio buttons. 
So I tried using the @IBAction with each button, I've this :

```
@IBAction func tona1_changed(_ sender: Any) {
 if test_tona1.isSelected == true
        {
            test_tona1.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "0b_unchecked"), for: UIControlState.normal)

            test_tona1.isSelected = false
        }
        else
        {
            test_tona1.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "0b_checked"), for: UIControlState.normal)

            test_tona1.isSelected = true
        }}
```

It actually make the image switch between "uncheck" and "check" but I don't know at all how to make it interact with the other buttons. 
I tried using an array with the buttons's tags inside but I didn't have something working. I also tried to make a class but I don't know how it can work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in several ways. One of the most trivial would be to:

- Have a datasource. Most of the time an array.
- Create an UIButton for each item in your datasource, and insert each button into another array. Each button would have a tag corresponding at the 
  index of the array. Also set different images for selected state and normal.
- Add an action for each button, with the target function being something like:

  ```
  func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton) {
      for button in buttons {
          button.isSelected = false
          // deselect your model datasource[button.tag]
      }

      sender.isSelected = true
      // select your model datasource[button.tag]
  }
  ```

I leave the abstraction / improvements / safety to you. The key point is just to use a collection of buttons, iterate through them, and select / deselect them accordingly, and **not** using a big if/else checking for the button tag everytime.

Comment: he can also select all buttons and grag it as an `Outlet Collection` from the interface builder to the code

Comment: Yes, but be careful by doing that as the Outlet Collection does not ensure that the order is respected. You have to sort it by tag on viewDidLoad, which may seem a little bit "hacky".